# Problema DatagridView C# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas quisiera que me ayuden por favor:

Estoy realizando un datagridview donde se pueden visualizar desde la base de datos. que en mi datagridview tiene estas columnas como imagen:
* Ticket

- Dias Falta.
- Fecha
- Estado
- Visualizar

Donde dice visualizar yo quiero que al presionar click se vallan esos datos  que estan en  datagridview otra pagina web con asp c# quisiera que me ayuden por favor para realizar la insercion en mi datagrid utilizo este codigo:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DtgConsultaIncidencia" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Bold="False" 
              Font-Italic  ="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"
              Width="100%" BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" ItemStyle-Height="23px" BorderStyle="Double" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DtgConsultaIncidencia_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#F8F8F8" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="11px" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="IdRegistroTareas" HeaderText="Ticket" ReadOnly="True">
            <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />

        </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DiasFaltantes" HeaderText="Dias Falta." ReadOnly="True">
            <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />
        </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ReportadoPor" HeaderText="Reportado Por" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False">
            <HeaderStyle Width="9%"/>
        </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Fecharegistro" HeaderText="Fecha" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
            <HeaderStyle Width="8%"/>
            <ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Agencia" HeaderText="Agencia" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False">
            <HeaderStyle Width="8%"/>
        </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="IdTarea" HeaderText="TipoIncidencia" ReadOnly="True">
            <HeaderStyle Width="12%"/>
            <ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:BoundColumn>

        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="IdEstadoTarea" HeaderText="Estado" ReadOnly="True">
            <HeaderStyle Width="10%"/>
        </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Visualizar" HeaderText="Visualizar" Text="--&gt;">
            <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />
        </asp:ButtonColumn>
    </Columns>
    <EditItemStyle BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <FooterStyle BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <HeaderStyle Height="25px" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="11px" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="11px" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <PagerStyle BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <SelectedItemStyle BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn = new SqlConnection("server=172.16.1.124;    database=DBProAuxQP_QA;      user id=sa;                   password=SA123456789*;");
            conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM TTareasIngreso ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            DtgConsultaIncidencia.DataSource = dt;

            DtgConsultaIncidencia.DataBind();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuidado con la puntuación en la pregunta. Pero aun así, o la pregunta no es clara, o es demasiada amplia, porque creo que tu pregunta se resume con esta sentencia: *Donde dice visualizar yo quiero que al presionar click se vallan esos datos a otra pagina web con asp c#*. Se necesitan mas detalles, y lo ideal es que lo hayas intentado primero.

Comment: @sstan muchas gracias ya resumi mas mi pregunta espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: @PieroDev, ¿lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: @fredyfx si hermano pero creo que lo han cerrado mi pregunta